# One Hot encoding for large number of values

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, classification, data-analysis, categorical-data

How do we use one hot encoding if the number of values which a categorical variable can take is large ?

In my case it is 56 values. So as per usual method I would have to add 56 columns (56 binary features) in the training dataset which will immensely increase the complexity and hence the training time.

So how do we deal with such cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a compact encoding.  This trades space for time, although one-hot encodings can often enjoy a very small time penalty.

The most accessible idea is a vector of 56 booleans, if your data format supports that.  The one with the most direct mapping is to use a 64-bit integer, each bit being a boolean.  This is how we implement one-hot vectors in hardware design.  Most 4G languages (and mature 3G languages) include fast routines for bit manipulation.  You will need get, set, clear, and find bits.

Does that get you moving?